# allowedCommonJsDependencies not recognized as valid property in angular.json

Tags: angular

I just updated my Angular app to version 10, and I got this warning in my console :

> WARNING in [MY_PROJECT_PATH]\node_modules@firebase\app\dist\index.cjs.js depends on '@firebase/util'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
> For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies

So I followed the link to check whats to do, and official website recommand to add the property "allowedCommonJsDependencies" into my angular config.

Problem is : I can't keep it because it s not considered as valid property and Angular refuse to compile du to this unsupported value.

Am I alone with this error ?

Answer (score 0):

I have no direct answer to my issue.

But after several tries, I finally updated some core packages and it start working magically :(